# Python creating 1 code with two codes (password validator&point system)

Tags: python

```
p = True
    while p:  
        if (len(p)<8 or len(p)>24):
            break
        elif not re.search("[a-z]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[0-9]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[!$%^&()_]",p):
            break
        else:
            print("Valid Password")
            p=False
            break

    if p:
        print("Not a Valid Password")
```

this code for above is the password validator to check if it contains a symbol upper case lower case number e.c.t

```
import re
import random
points = 0
print("""
Point System:
~1 Uppercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 Lowercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 From 0-9 = 5 Points
~1 Allocated Symbol = 5 Points
~If Has All Add 10 Points
""")


while points < 35:
    p = input("Input Password: ")


    if 8 <= len(p) < 24 :
        print(len(p),"Points Added - Length")
        points += (len(p))

    else:
        print("Wrong length, it must be 8 to 24 characters")
        continue

    if re.search("[a-z]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter")
        points += 5

    if re.search("[0-9]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Number")
        points += 5

    if re.search("[A-Z]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter")
        points += 5

    if re.search("[!$%^&()_]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Symbols")
        points += 5

    if points == 20:
        points += 10

    print("You have {} points".format(points))
    break
```

this code above is  the point system however i would like to make it so that unless the user has all of the allocated characters it doesn't run the points

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import random
points = 0
print("""
Point System:
~1 Uppercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 Lowercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 From 0-9 = 5 Points
~1 Allocated Symbol = 5 Points
~If Has All Add 10 Points
""")

def pwdVal(pwd):
    while pwd:  
        if (len(p)<8 or len(p)>24):
            break
        elif not re.search("[a-z]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[0-9]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[!$%^&()_]",p):
            break
        else:
            print("Valid Password")
            return True
            break

while points < 35:
    p = input("Input Password: ")
    if pwdVal(p):
        if 8 <= len(p) < 24 :
            print(len(p),"Points Added - Length")
            points += (len(p))

        else:
            print("Wrong length, it must be 8 to 24 characters")
            continue

        if re.search("[a-z]", p):
            print("5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter")
            points += 5

        if re.search("[0-9]", p):
            print("5 Points Added - Number")
            points += 5

        if re.search("[A-Z]", p):
            print("5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter")
            points += 5

        if re.search("[!$%^&()_]", p):
            print("5 Points Added - Symbols")
            points += 5

        if points == 20:
            points += 10

        print("You have {} points".format(points))
        break
    else:
        print("Not a Valid Password")
```

Sample run

```
Point System:
~1 Uppercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 Lowercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 From 0-9 = 5 Points
~1 Allocated Symbol = 5 Points
~If Has All Add 10 Points

Input Password: DDDDDD
Not a Valid Password
Input Password: sssssssssssss
Not a Valid Password
Input Password: sssssssssssss@@#SSSqq11
Not a Valid Password
Input Password: a!123aaAAss
Valid Password
11 Points Added - Length
5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter
5 Points Added - Number
5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter
5 Points Added - Symbols
You have 31 points
```